# 'Isn't this a standard?' vs. 'Is this not a standard?'

Tags: sentence-structure

I know that the first sentence '*Isn't* this a standard?' is grammatically correct, but sometimes I have encountered the usage like 'is this *not* a standard?', putting *not* behind the subject *this*. Is the second sentence form acceptable? If it is acceptable, is there any difference in their tone?

Comment: Both are OK. Obviously the emphasis is on "not" in the second example.

Comment: What @user3169 said. The second form is bound to be less common overall, but it emphasises ***not*** more, so it works better in contexts where the speaker actually thinks it *should* be a standard (and is surprised that it's not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To make an answer out of this since one hasn't been made in two days...)

As @user3169 said, they're both okay. And as @FumbleFingers said, the extra emphasis is on *not*, which has the function of suggesting surprise at discovering that it's not a standard.

> Is this not a standard? (Because I thought it was, but you're telling me it's not.)

By contrast, the more common "isn't" could be used with different intonations for a couple of purposes:

> Isn't this a standard? (I want to confirm my understanding.)
>
> Isn't this a standard? (I'm politely reminding you of the fact.)
>
> Isn't this a standard? (Because I thought it was, but you're telling me it's not.)